# Email a Friend functionality in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mail

Pretty much there would be an icon on the site. clicking it would bring up a pop up window with following fieds:

1. Name
2. Email

you would then be able to fill out the page and an email would be sent to "email" provided in the "Email" field. The problem is: How do i know what page i'm on so that I can put it in the message?
thanks

Comment: in javascript: window.location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")
@ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller")
```

should contain the current controller and action which you could use. you could also extract other route parameters like:

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"]
```

So this information could be posted to the controller action that is going to send the email:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(
    "Send", 
    "Email", 
    new { 
        currentAction = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action"), 
        currentController = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller") 
    }, 
    FormMethod.Post)
)
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Email)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send email!" />
}
```

And the action that will send the email:

```
public ActionResult Send(string name, string email, string currentAction, string currentController)
{
    // TODO: based on the value of the current action and controller send
    // the email
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Email send functionality in ASP.net [Example Code](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Sending-email-from-ASP-NET-MVC-through-MVC-and-MSMQ-Part1.aspx)
Refer this code and implement in your code. It will be helpful.